# How to update R in terminal?

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install dplyr and tidyr packages in R, but i get the following message:

> Installing package into '/home/datadude/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0'
>   (as 'lib' is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>   package 'dplyr' is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

I assume that I need to update R, but I am running it on a server that has Ubuntu 14.04 and I am not really proficient in terminal. Tried the following thing:

```
sudo su
echo "deb http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/" >> 
/etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

This updated bunch of stuff, but I still get the same message when I try to install these packages.

Comment: No, unfortunately, this one didn't work either.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html gives instruction : note that 14.04 is trusty not precise